# Ordinary kriging in QGIS with geodetic coordinates

Tags: qgis, kriging, geodetic

I am using QGIS 3.16.9 Hannover. I want to create a surface (with kriging) from a list of points whose SRC is WGS84, so I am working with geodetic coordinates. They are in decimal degrees covering a surface of 10km x 9km. I can see the points correctly-

My problem comes with the "Ordinary Kriging" setup. I unchecked "block kriging" and used the following options:

```
quality measure: stand. dev.
Logarithmic transf.
variogram model: linear
fit:nodes
search range: local
search directions: all directions
number of points: max. number of points
```

But when I have to fill "cell size", "maximum search distance, block size.. etc", it seems I need to use units that are not in degrees or I don't understand those units. I tried to use decimal degrees units but then the number of iterations was so high that my computer hangs.

I have already asked this question in the QGIS list and the only one answer was that I should project the data and then interpolate.
It doesn't make sense to me. There are other softwares that I can you to do this whithout the need of projeting first. But I would like to use QGIS for this, not just a "visor" of things obtained outside.
So, does anybody knows how to do this?

Let's say I want a grid of 10x9km and a grid step of 100m (or 0.001 degree). Is there a way to do this in QGIS without projecting the data?

Comment: Most people would be against doing Kriging on geographical coordinates, but I sometimes do. How about setting the cellsize = 0.001, maximum distance = 0.2,  or somewhere around these figures?